# cancel socket listener after receiving response - flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, sockets

I have a socket connection to a router using flutter.
first I connect to router and send a message.
then I create a listener to get router response, but after receiving response I have to close the listener.
how can I do that?

```
Socket socket = await Socket.connect(
                      ip,
                      port,
                      timeout: Duration(seconds: 3),
                    );

                    socket.add(
                      ascii.encode('status'),
                    );

                    socket.listen(
                      (List<int> event) {
                        Provider.of<relayStatus>(context, listen: false)
                            .setRelayStatus = utf8.decode(event);
                        Navigator.push(
                          context,
                          MaterialPageRoute(
                            builder: (context) => OnOffPage(
                              socket,
                            ),
                          ),
                        );
                      },
                    );
```

Answer (score 0):

- socket.onDisconnect((_) => print('disconnect'));
  this Method use  For Response Get   after  This Function Call

Comment: there is not such a method for socket